# SQL where or having in

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to keep this in one query if possible.  basically, I want to get the ID of anyone seen in the last 5 days or have been seen more than twice and keep it in the same query.  If splitting it into a couple sub queries or temp tables is the best route to go then I can go that route.  I just want to keep it as condensed as possible.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
select ID,Name
from some table a
where cast(a.[appointment date] as date) > cast(GETDATE() - 5 as date)
group by id,name
or having count(id) > 2
```

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the date condition to the `HAVING` clause:

```
select ID, Name
from sometable a
group by id, name
having count(id) > 2
    or max(cast(a.[appointment date] as date)) > cast(GETDATE() - 5 as date)
```

Comment: @bertj, this is subtly different to query in the question and may not return the same results.

Comment: @Jodrell, maybe I didn't read carefully enough, but what's the difference?

Comment: Well, this will only filter the by the maximum `[appointment date]` in the group and will include rows that don't match that criterion in the count.

Comment: @Jodrell, "I want to get the ID of anyone seen in the last 5 days or have been seen more than twice".

Comment: yep, it does that.

Comment: @Jodrell I do see what you mean.  The answers and explanations are great.  This has helped get me down the right path.

Answer (score 0):

I hope below query answers your question.

select ID
from sometable a
where cast(a.[appointment date] as date) > cast(GETDATE() - 5 as date)
group by id
having count(id) > 2

Answer (score 0):

To do the same thing as the attempted query in the question.

```
SELECT
            [Filtered].[Id],
            [Filtered].[Name]
    FROM
            (
                SELECT
                            [Id],
                            [Name]
                    FROM
                            [some table] [A]
                    WHERE
                            CAST([A].[appointment date] AS DATE) >
                                CAST(GETDATE() - 5 AS DATE)
            ) [Filtered]
     GROUP BY
                 [Filtered].[Id],
                 [Filtered].[Name]
         HAVING
                 COUNT([Filtered].[Id]) > 2
```